# iOS:Is it possible to change appearance of a UI element back to default appearance?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem

I am setting appearance of UIBarButtonItem using -appearance method.
How can I change it back to iOS default appearance?
Here I am changing appearance of UIBarButtonItem:

```
   NSDictionary *textAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                [UIColor colorWithHex:0x3A4047], 
                                UITextAttributeTextColor, 
                                [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:0.0], 
                                UITextAttributeTextShadowColor, 
                                [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:13.0], 
                                UITextAttributeFont, 
                                nil];

 [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:textAttributes                                                
                                            forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Now at some point can I revert all that appearance proxies that I have applied to default proxies?

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: @Neeku I have edited my question, please provide your valuable suggestions.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:nil
                                                forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: I am gonna try it and let you know if it works or not.

Comment: Not able to change appearance proxies for already created UIBarbuttonItem. First I need to set current appearance proxies to nil and then create the UIBarButtonItem. Does it work like that?

Answer (score 1):

Create an `NSDictionary` with all of the default attributes before you create `*textAttributes`. Then when you want to make it default set the attributes to the other `NSDictionary`.

Comment: Thats a good idea, but since we have lot of attributes I don't want to create bunch of dictionaries for various UI elements I want to apply styles for.

Comment: I'm saying you create one NSDictionary of what you would call the default attributes that you would want. You can reuse your dictionary, you don't need to make a bunch of them.

Comment: How would you get default proxies if you reuse your dictionary? Don't you think you need to store all the default proxies for all the UI elements before you actually apply different appearance proxies to them?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: so that way you will have a dictionary per UI element.

Comment: Yes, each element would have its own defined default.